# How to space out labels on Y-Axis aChartEngine Android

Tags: android, achartengine

Good day, i have a slight issue. i have created my own Labels on the Y-Axis with the following code below, but they are so clustered together, How can i space them out?.

Here is my code:

```
 renderer.setYLabels(0); 

//value_value is an array which would use as the labels for the y axis

    int value_size = value_value.length;
        int m = 0;
        //int add =  value_size/10;
        int add =  largest_size/10;   // largest_size is the biggest value in the array value_value


        for(int i=0; i< 10; i++){

            if(m > value_value.length){
                 break;
             }
            renderer.addYTextLabel((double)i, value_value[m].toString(), 1);
            m+=add;
        }
```

P.S: from the api docs, there is a 3rd parameter "int scale" which i thought would help me space out the margins but i never seem to use it correctly. if i put any value there, i get a NullPointerException. What does it really do and how to use it?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

My Graph:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding custom labels can be tricky because you always have to make sure you are not overlapping them. You should add only as many as needed to avoid overlapping. You can also listen for pan and zoom events and update the custom labels accordingly.

The `scale` parameter is useful when you have multiple Y axis scales. If you don't have then you don't need to use the parameter.

Comment: sorry for the late response and thanks for taking the time to look at it. i only want to add 10 units on the y-axis (probably on the x-axis as well). is the scaling having to do with the amount of space the graph can fit in the view? cos from my graph, the x-axis is wider than the y-axis, so the value of 10 units fits correctly there. i have edited my question and added my graph for you to see.

Comment: the y-axis value is by default. if i add it with the code above, it gets clustered

Comment: The scaling has nothing to do with the thing you mentioned.

Comment: sorry i didn't mean scaling with regard to the parameter, i meant more like stretching the axis. thanks anyway